# LazyInitializationException with ModelMapper (Spring + Hibernate)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, modelmapper

Two tables in DB: `TAB_A` and `TAB_B`. Relation between tables "one to one" on `prop` column.

In my application I have 2 use cases:

- Use case 1: `select * from TAB_A`;
- Use case 2: `select * from TAB_A join TAB_B on prop`.

In *both* cases I use a ModelMapper instance to map entities to DTOs.

With no rule:

- UC1 -> `LazyInitializationException`
- UC2 -> OK

With `skip().setProp(null)`:

- UC1 -> OK
- UC2 -> `prop` value is not shown (obviously)

I've tried also conditional mapping, but with no success. How can I set the configuration mapper in order to avoid any problem in both cases?

Hibernate 3.5 + Spring 4.3

Comment: Could you provide your Java models? Do you use spring data? Does `ModelMapper` work in `@Transactional` method?

Comment: @MaxFarsikov thanks. Using `@Transactional` on the source method for the mapping solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `@Transactional` annotation looks like a sloppy fix, and to realy fix the problem I would recommend to remove it, and avoid Lazy loading (use Eager instead) in your entities.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Anyway I have to avoid EAGER load for performance reasons. There are problems related to use of @Transactional annotation?

Comment: But you do not use that laziness, because mapper causes loading anyway (that is why you need open transaction during DTO mapping), and you achieve even worse performance than with eager loading. And solution with `@Transaction` is also  called 'open session in view antipattern` (your DTO is technically a view)